# how take dice value from dice script to the stone script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to access dicevalue from the dice script in the stone script. Sothe stone can move according to the dice values. I trying this on monopoly.

Dice.cs

```
public class dice : MonoBehaviour
    {
    Rigidbody rb;

    bool haslanded;
    bool thrown;

    Vector3 initPosition;

    public int dicevalue;

    public DiceSide[] diceSides;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        initPosition = transform.position;
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
           {
                 RollDice();
           }

        if(rb.IsSleeping() && !haslanded && thrown)
         {
            haslanded = true;
            rb.useGravity = false;
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            SideValueCheck();
        }
        else if (rb.IsSleeping() && haslanded && dicevalue ==0)
        {
            RollAgain();
        }
    }
    void RollDice()
    {
        if (!thrown && !haslanded)
        {
            thrown = true;
            rb.useGravity = true;
            rb.AddTorque(Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500));
        }
        else if (thrown && haslanded)
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }

        void Reset()
        {
            transform.position = initPosition;
            thrown = false;
            haslanded = false;
            rb.useGravity = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        }
    
    void RollAgain()
    {
        Reset();
        thrown = true;
        rb.useGravity = true;
        rb.AddTorque(Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500));

    }

    void SideValueCheck()
    {
        dicevalue = 0;
        foreach (DiceSide side in diceSides)
        {
            if(side.onGround())
            {
                dicevalue = side.sideValue;
                Debug.Log(dicevalue + "has been rolled");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

stone.cs

```
      using System.Collections;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using UnityEngine;

      public class Stone : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public Route currentRoute;
    int routePosition;
    public int steps;
    bool isMoving;
   

     void Update()
    {
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isMoving)
        {
            steps = Random.Range(1, 12);
```

here maybe i can use getcomponent. but it is not working. the player(stone is not moving on pressing space.

```
            Debug.Log("Dice Rolled" );
            StartCoroutine(Move()); 
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Move()
    {
        if(isMoving)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        isMoving = true;
         while(steps>0)
        {
            routePosition++;
            routePosition %= currentRoute.childnodeList.Count;

            Vector3 nextPos = currentRoute.childnodeList[routePosition].position;
            while (MoveToNextNode(nextPos)) { yield return null; }


            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            steps--;

        }


        isMoving = false;
    }  
    bool MoveToNextNode(Vector3 goal)
    {
        return goal != (transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, goal, 8f * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to make use of the dicevalue field on the Dice class shown.

Answer (score 0):

To get value `diceValue` from Dice.cs, on Stone.cs use:

```
FindObjectOfType<Dice>().diceValue;
```

FindObjectOfType will return the first instance of Dice script it can find in the scene, if there are multiple dice use FindObjectsOfType and get the object based on index. From there, you can access the public variable `diceValue` using `.diceValue`. (assuming that Dice.cs and Stone.cs are scripts attached to `GameObjects`).